# Fixed Distance Buffer Gives Inaccurate Distances

Tags: distance, buffer, global

I have a world map shapefile showing all continents. Each of the shapefile is projected and I need to buffer each of the continents with a 1000 km buffer, but all my buffers show incorrect distances near the polar regions. They appear to be fixed-width as opposed to fixed-distance. They should look distorted near the poles. Am I missing something?

Comment: What projection are you using for all major continents? When you say *major* continents which of the 7 are missing? What software are you using to do the buffering? How are you evaluating the buffer distances?

Comment: Pseudo-Mercator; all 7 continents present, redundant wording on my part; QGIS- A Coruna; using the standard vector geometry buffer tool

Comment: Web Mercator gives inaccurate distances. You can't use it to make accurate buffers.

Comment: Do you mean EPSG:3857 Web Mercator? Are you aware that mercator projection isn't so good at distances but works well enough for bearings? https://connectusfund.org/13-major-pros-and-cons-of-mercator-projection has a list of pros and cons of mercator over large distances. There's also a few good graphics with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection to illustrate the issues as you get further away from the equator.